# Jaxb generated sources with nullable fields

Tags: jaxb, nullable

I have kotlin project where I'm using Jaxb generated src files from xsd. The problem with these generated sources is that they have `nullable` fields but IDEA does not know about it. It can lead to bugs in `production`. To fix it we can add `@Nullable` annotation to all getters in generated srs-es.

How can we do it gracefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this solution, it works for me but maybe somebody knows better approuch?

Gradle kt task

```kotlin
tasks.register("nullableForXsdFields") {
    group = "code generation"
    description = "Add Nullable annotation to generated jaxb files"
    actions.add {
        val xjcFiles = fileTree("$buildDir/generated-sources/main/xjc")
        xjcFiles.forEach { xjcFile ->
            var content = xjcFile.readText()
            Regex("(public) (\\w+|<|>|\\*) (get)").findAll(content).distinct()
                .forEach { match ->
                    content = content.replace(
                        match.groups[0]!!.value,
                        match.groups[0]!!.value.replace("public ", "public @Nullable ")
                    )
                }.run {
                    content = content.replace(
                        "import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;",
                        "import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;\nimport org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;"
                    )
                }
            xjcFile.writeBytes(content.toByteArray())
        }
    }
}
tasks.getByName("xjcGeneration").finalizedBy("nullableForXsdFields")
tasks.getByName("compileKotlin").dependsOn("nullableForXsdFields")
tasks.getByName("compileJava").dependsOn("nullableForXsdFields")
```

`xjcGeneration` - is my plugin to generate src from xsd

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, so I've created an extension for *maven* jaxb plugin
`com.github.labai:labai-jsr305-jaxb-plugin`.

This extension marks all generated packages as *nullable* by default, and then marks with *@NotNull* only those fields, which are mandatory by xsd scheme.

You can find more details how to use it with maven in github
https://github.com/labai/labai-jsr305

Comment: what about jaxb2-maven-plugin ? Will it work with that plugin as well ?

Comment: it works with both _maven-jaxb2-plugin_ and _jaxb2-maven-plugin_, some examples are provided in project